# Some confusion on the description of read consistency in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, data-consistency

Below is a short brief of read consistency from oracle concepts guide.

What is a sql statement, just one sql? Or Pl/SQL or Store Procedure? Anyone can help provide me one opposite example which can indicates the un-consistency read?

```
 read consistency 
    A consistent view of data seen by a user. For example, in statement-level read
    consistency the set of data seen by a SQL statement remains constant throughout
    statement execution.
```

Comment: When you read a table, it can be under some update process, so the data can be un-consistent or "dirty". There are some configurations that let you choose if you want to get this dirty data, or if you prefer to wait the transaction be commited before retrieving the data. In a nutshell, in some familiar words, this is what it means

Comment: Thanks @ Jaime Drq, BTW ,what does 'a SQL statement' refer to?

Comment: A SQL statement is a query that you run on your RDBMS to get the data you want (in this context). However, a SQL statement can be also a INSERT statement, an UPDATE statement, a DELETE statement... All of them are members of SQL language, so all of them are SQL statements.

Comment: So a sql statemet is one sql Or PL/SQL or Store Procedure ?@Jaime Drq

Comment: @Tom: no. As referred to above, "a SQL statement" means a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement. It does NOT mean "a PL/SQL statement". It does NOT mean "a stored procedure". It means "a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement". Due to the way MERGE statements work I'm not sure if MERGE statements can be included in the above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Jaime Drq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "statement" in this context is one DML statement: a single `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`.

It is *not* a PL/SQL block.  Similarly, multiple executions of the same DML statement (say, within a PL/SQL loop) are separate "statements".  If you need consistency over multiple statements or within a PL/SQL block, you can achieve that using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` or `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY`.  Both introduce limitations.

An opposite example of an inconsistent read would be as follows.

Starting conditions: table `BIG_TABLE` has 10 million rows.

User A at 10:00:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BIG_TABLE;
```

User B at 10:01:

```
DELETE FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE ID >= 9000000;  -- delete the last million rows
```

User B at 10:02:

```
COMMIT;
```

User A at 10:03: query completes:

```
COUNT(*)
--------------
9309129
```

That is wrong.  User A should have either gotten 10 million rows or 9 million rows.  At no point were there 9309129 *committed* rows in the table.  What has happened is that user A had read 309,129 rows that user B was deleting before Oracle actually processed the deletion (or before the `COMMIT`).  Then, after the user B delete/commit, user A's query stopped seeing the deleted rows and stopped counting them.

This sort of problem is impossible in Oracle, thanks to its implementation of Multiversion Read Consistency.

In Oracle, in the above situation, as it encountered blocks that had rows deleted (and committed) by User B, User A's query would have used the UNDO data reconstruct what those blocks looked like at 10:00 -- the time when user A's query started.

That's basically it -- Oracle statements operate on the a version of the database as it existed as of a single point in time.  This point in time is almost always the time when the statement started.  There are some exception cases involving updates when that point in time will be moved to a point in time "mid statement".  But it is always consistent as of one point in time or another.

Comment: Thanks a lot,very helpful @Matthew McPeak